# MSI failing to install, error log inside

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-installer

I am unable to install an msi from a custom web application I have developed. I am trying to install the msi on windows server 2008 R2 Datacenter Service pack 1 amazon machine. The installer keeps giving an error to exit and reopen the installer. I was able to run the installed with a log - below is part of the log - if more is needed please let me know. Any reason why this msi would not just install like previous versions? Changed may have been made to the machine I work on but I was not able to find any that should give an error. Thank you.

```
=== Logging stopped: 1/30/2012  9:02:41 ===
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:012]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:012]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:012]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM    `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708 
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:012]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:012]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:012]: Product: WebSetup1 -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:017]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name:     WebSetup1. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft.     Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:026]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:026]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:028]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 1/30/2012  9:02:41 ===
```

here is another part of the log

```
Action 9:02:37: IsolateComponents. 
Action start 9:02:37: IsolateComponents.
Action ended 9:02:37: IsolateComponents. Return value 0.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:815]: Doing action: WEBCA_GatherAppPools
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:815]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 9:02:37: WEBCA_GatherAppPools. 
Action start 9:02:37: WEBCA_GatherAppPools.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:815]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT     `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action`     = 'WEBCA_GatherAppPools' 
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:817]: Creating MSIHANDLE (24) of type 790542 for thread 2576
MSI (c) (D8:A8) [09:02:37:818]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:     C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\MSI16B1.tmp, Entrypoint: GatherAppPools
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:828]: Creating MSIHANDLE (25) of type 790531 for thread 3008
INFO   : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:828] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom     Action is starting...
INFO   : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:828] [GatherAppPools                          ]:     CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:836]: Creating MSIHANDLE (26) of type 790541 for thread 3008
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:836]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ComboBox 
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:836]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: ComboBox 4: INSERT INTO `ComboBox`     (`Property`,`Order`,`Value`,`Text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) TEMPORARY 
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:837]: Closing MSIHANDLE (26) of type 790541 for thread 3008
ERROR  : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:837] [GatherAppPools                          ]: FAILED:      -2147023281
ERROR  : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:838] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom     Action failed with code: '1615'
INFO   : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:839] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom       Action completed with return code: '1615'
INFO   : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:839] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom     Action completed with return code: '1615'
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:840]: Closing MSIHANDLE (25) of type 790531 for thread 3008
CustomAction WEBCA_GatherAppPools returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be     100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (c) (D8:A8) [09:02:37:841]: Closing MSIHANDLE (24) of type 790542 for thread 2576
Action ended 9:02:37: WEBCA_GatherAppPools. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:842]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:842]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 9:02:37: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 9:02:37: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:842]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT     `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action`     = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:844]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:844]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2826 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the     boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are:     FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the     system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif'     font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif'     font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2826 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the     boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are:     FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2826 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the     boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are:     FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
Action 9:02:37: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (D8:3C) [09:02:37:852]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 
Action ended 9:02:40: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
Action ended 9:02:40: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:002]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (D8:8C) [09:02:41:003]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
```

here are the 2 spots where the errors are, return value 3

```
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:837]: Closing MSIHANDLE (26) of type 790541 for thread 3008
ERROR  : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:837] [GatherAppPools                          ]: FAILED:      -2147023281
ERROR  : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:838] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom     Action failed with code: '1615'
INFO   : [01/30/2012 09:02:37:839] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom     Action completed with return code: '1615'
MSI (c) (D8!C0) [09:02:37:840]: Closing MSIHANDLE (25) of type 790531 for thread 3008
CustomAction WEBCA_GatherAppPools returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be     100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (c) (D8:A8) [09:02:37:841]: Closing MSIHANDLE (24) of type 790542 for thread 2576
Action ended 9:02:37: WEBCA_GatherAppPools. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:842]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm

MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:842]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 9:02:37: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 9:02:37: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:37:842]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT     `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action`     = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:844]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:844]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2826 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the     boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are:     FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the     system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:846]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif'     font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif'     font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2826 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the     boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are:     FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (D8:34) [09:02:37:847]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM     `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2826 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the     boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are:     FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
Action 9:02:37: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (D8:3C) [09:02:37:852]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 
Action ended 9:02:40: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
Action ended 9:02:40: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (D8:10) [09:02:41:002]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WEBCA_GatherAppPools` custom is failing with 1615 error code. The code translated to: `SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported`. There is a problem in the SQL syntax you use to insert items in the combo-box.